# AWS EventBridge Cloudtrail Log ResponeElement Tag

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-cloudtrail, aws-event-bridge

I'm trying to get the alert which the user fails to log in to the AWS console.
I wrote the event bridge rule based on the cloud trail log.
Raw Log

```
{
    "eventVersion": "1.08",
    "userIdentity": {
        "type": "IAMUser",
        "principalId": "XXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "accountId": "XXXXXXXXXXX",
        "accessKeyId": "",
        "userName": "XXXXXXXX"
    },
    "eventTime": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "eventSource": "signin.amazonaws.com",
    "eventName": "ConsoleLogin",
    "awsRegion": "us-east-1",
    "sourceIPAddress": "XXXXXXXXX",
    "userAgent": "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; Win64; x64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/92.0.4515.107 Safari/537.36",
    "errorMessage": "Failed authentication",
    "requestParameters": null,
    "responseElements": {
        "ConsoleLogin": "Failure"
    },
```

Here I want to take the Input as the `ConsoleLogin": "Failure"` How to create a rule in Eventbridge.

EventBridge Rule.

```
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS Console Sign In via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "eventSource": [
      "signin.amazonaws.com"
    ],
    "eventName": [
      "ConsoleLogin"
    ],
    "type": [
      "Root",
      "AssumedRole",
      "IAMUser"
    ],
    "responseElements": {
      "ConsoleLogin": [
        "Failure"
      ]
    }
  }
}
```

Is this the Right rule.

Comment: Have you tried yourself? What was the response?

Comment: I tried but EventBridge didn't respond when an event triggers from CloudTrail.

Comment: I've tried and the rule above and it worked fine. Failed login was detected with EventBridge and notified with SNS. I had similar problem once and just re-creation all things worked (at that time. Used [this cfn.](https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/root-user-account-cloudwatch-rule/?nc1=h_ls) ) .

Comment: Still, the same Problem Even changes the EventBridge rule.

This is the Event Rule.
{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ],
  "detail": {
    "userIdentity": {
      "type": [
        "Root",
        "AssumedRole",
        "IAMUser"
      ]
    },
    "responseElements": {
      "ConsoleLogin": [
        "Failure"
      ]
    }
  }
}

Comment: If I edit with this one then only it working.

{
  "detail-type": [
    "AWS API Call via CloudTrail"
  ]
}